# Size of pointer ( *variable VS variable)

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

Based on my understanding On 32-bit machine sizeof pointer is 32 bits ( 4 bytes), while on 64 bit machine it's 8 byte. Regardless of what data type they are pointing to, they have fixed size. My computer is running on 64bit, but when i print the size of including the * i get 4 . Why is that so ? whats the difference between printing the variable and printing the *variable.

```
   int *name = NULL;
    int *add = NULL;

    cout<< sizeof (*name) << endl; // Prints 4
    cout << sizeof (add); //Prints 8
```

Comment: Because one is a pointer, and the other one isn't?

Comment: It does seem strange that you start out talking about the size of pointers, but then switch to the size of the pointed-to object for your question.

Answer (score 5):

The `*` operator **dereferences** a pointer.  In other words, it gives you what it points to.

`name` has type `int *`, so `*name` has type `int`.  That means `sizeof(*name)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, which on your system is 4.

Likewise, `add` has type `int *`.  That means `sizeof(add)` is the same as `sizeof(int *)`, which on your system is 8.

Answer (score 0):

Because `sizeof (*name)` is not the same as `sizeof (name)`. The former is an `int`, not a `int *`. An `int` is likely 4 bytes on most architectures.

Comment: It's OK to dereference null in an unevaluated operand (such as the argument to `sizeof`)

Comment: Do you have a source that says that?

Comment: Yeah, see the standard

Answer (score 0):

the two instructions

`sizeof (*name)` and `sizeof (add)` are completely different.

In the case of `sizeof (add)` you are requiring the size of a pointer, 64 bits( 8 Bytes) as you correctly analyze.

In the case of `sizeof (*name)`, the instruction first dereferences the pointer, and then apply the sizeof funtion on the dereferenced pointer ( over the **int**). So the result will be 32 bits (4 Bytes). This because also in the 64-bit architectures the int can be of 32 bits.

This works because sizeof is a compile time construct. If we look at the **C99** draft standard section *6.5.3.4* The sizeof operator paragraph 2 says(emphasis mine):

> [...] The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result
>   is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not
>   evaluated and the result is an integer constant.